# Receiving all columns with StringBuilder

Tags: java, mysql

I've written a method that performs the following commands: select, insert, update, delete. Originally, I only wanted the first two columns of output after running `SELECT * FROM SithLords`. How can I get all of the rows and columns? Also, how can I allow the user to add newlines when running the select command like this:

`SELECT jedi_name
   FROM SithLords
   WHERE level = 'master';`

As of now, it only executes with one line:

`select jedi_name from SithLords where level = 'master';`

**Code:**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String query = queryStatements.getText();
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query);
            if(query.matches("(select|SELECT).*")) {
                ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
                StringBuilder strResult = new StringBuilder();
                while(result.next()) {
                    strResult.append(result.getString(1)).append(" ").append(result.getString(2));
                    strResult.append("\n");
                }
                queryResults.setText(strResult.toString());
            } else if(query.matches("(insert|INSERT).*")) {
                stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            } else if(query.matches("(update|UPDATE).*")) {
               stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            } else if(query.matches("(delete|DELETE).*")) {
               stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            } else {
               System.out.println("Not supported yet!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException error) {
          error.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question at all.

Comment: @nachokk I'll re-edit it. All done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to retrieve from the recorset all its columns you could ask it how many columns does it have (n) and access from 1 to n:

```
ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
ResultSetMetaData md = result.getMetaData();
int nCols = md.getColumnCount();
for(int c = 1; c <= nCols; c++)
  strResult.append(result.getString(c).append(" "));
```

Concerning your multiline commands, you could replace the command end of lines by spaces:

```
query.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", " ");
```

Comment: Ah, so in turn it really removes all instances of space into one line. I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks for pointing that out Pablo!

Comment: Oh, shouldn't ```nCols``` be of type Int?

Comment: Yes,its a code fragment but I'll edit to include ncols declaration

Comment: I'm getting an sql exception of before start of result set.

Comment: @TheGrayFox at prepareStatement?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking.

Comment: @TheGreyFox check the replace is replacing with spaces: second parameter

Comment: Haha, nailed it. Thanks for the help once again :-)